# "Device has either stopped responding or been disconnected" after removing phone from PC

Tags: windows-10, android

My Windows 10 PC is about a year old; my Android S21 Ultra (Android 12) is about 6 months old

In the last two months a few hours after disconnecting my phone, my PC starts displaying "**Device has either stopped responding or been disconnected**" messages with "Galaxy S21 Ultra 5g" in the title bar.   These messages will occur several times a day until I reboot the PC.   But since the PC runs 24/7 with only one or two restarts a week, that may be a long time.

All over the web, including on this website at least twice, there is advice that phones do not need to be "ejected" because they are MTP devices, not file systems.   And, indeed, there is no obvious way to eject them.   Yet this is exactly the sort of message I would expect if something wasn't properly dismounted before being disconnected.

But just the same, I've been very careful to never disconnect my phone in the middle of a file transfer.  So why am I getting these messages?  And why only now, and not since I got this phone?  [image]

**Edit:**  I did a web search and found this heavily-reported on Reddit:   https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/otpmaf/the_device_has_either_stopped_responding_or_has/
But no helpful advice there.

Comment: Do you have any Samsung software installed related to your phone?

Comment: No, none whatsoever.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/device-has-stopped-responding-or-has-been/7c994d73-0082-4783-b0ed-ac97730551d1#?page=2 
ShannonN3's comment on page 2.

Comment: Connection mode depends on USB controller config. Several are available, like for example MTP, PTP, MIDI, USB Tether or Charger only.

Comment: Have You Tried Nir Sofers Tool? [http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html] ... USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB devices that you previously used, and disconnect USB devices that are currently connected...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this may be a "this works for me" answer, but it may be helpful for someone else.

1. Open Windows Settings page *Bluetooth & other devices*
2. Find your phone in the list of devices
3. Right click on the phone and click on *Remove Device*

This is based on @Gantendo's comment above, and ShannonN3's solution in [the thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/device-has-stopped-responding-or-has-been/7c994d73-0082-4783-b0ed-ac97730551d1#?page=2) it refers to.

--EDIT--

Unfortunately the "works for me" solution only worked for < 24 hours. I tried unplugging and plugging in the phone a few times and it the message didn't reappear... But the following morning the error message was back. The phone didn't reappear in the list of *Bluetooth & other devices* so add this to the list of failed solutions.

Comment: No problem with this answer, IMHO.  It's perfectly acceptable to take information from the comments and make it part of an answer, *especially* if you've validated that it worked for you (and, of course, is different from the other others, which it is).

Answer (score 0):

Wait until your computer starts doing this and don't restart your computer. Launch device manager (run > devmgmt.msc). Do you see anything listed under 'Android Phone' or 'Portable Devices'? If you do see anything that isn't plugged in try right clicking and pick Remove Device

If you don't see anything, leave the window up on a second monitor (or split screen). It will refresh on its own when there is a hardware change. Does it refresh before another message is shown?

Comment: No nothing listed under Android Phone (or anything else with Android...) nor under Portable devices.     Meanwhile today on a totally different Windows 10 computer we started getting the same message after unplugging her Nikon Z6II camera from the USB port.     And meanwhile this problem about getting this error message about phantom USB devices continues to be reported all over the web with only "it worked for me" folk-medicine "solutions".